# How to read a Binary Document from Couchbase - JavaSDK API

Tags: java, file, couchbase

I am trying to insert and retrieve small files in couchbase, insertion is successful but when I try to fetch the content and write it to a file am getting below error.

```
    BinaryDocument responsefromDB = bucket.get("KESAVAN", BinaryDocument.class);
    try {
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Satz\\Test - Copy\\Output.txt");
        ostream.write(responsefromDB.content().array());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: direct buffer
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.array(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:363)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.buffer.SlicedByteBuf.array(SlicedByteBuf.java:97)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.array(CompositeByteBuf.java:463)
    at com.util.task.CouchbaseClient.main(CouchbaseClient.java:52)

Answer (score 1):

You can only access the `array()` if `hasArray()` returns true. Otherwise the Netty buffer itself is backed by native memory. In this case you will need to use one of its `getBytes(...)` methods to copy the content to an array.

*Don't forget* to `release()` the buffer after obtaining it (in the `finally` block of your try catch for instance).

You seem to be outputing the content into a text file, so is `BinaryDocument` really what you're after? Maybe `StringDocument` would be a better, less hurdle, fit? (see http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.1/documents-basics.html).

Note that if you still have a compelling reason to use `BinaryDocument` and want the output as a `String`, you can use `ByteBuf.toString(Charset)` for this instead of `getBytes`.

Comment: Great it worked. Thanks!   Actually I want to read/write small video/audio files